# Wanting to understand purpose and count of V8's WorkerThread(s)

Tags: v8, embedded-v8

I have a very simple program as follows that just creates an isolate, then sleeps:

```
#include <libplatform/libplatform.h>
#include <v8-platform.h>
#include <v8.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using v8::Isolate;

int main() {

   std::unique_ptr<v8::Platform> platform = v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform();
   v8::V8::InitializePlatform(platform.get());
   v8::V8::Initialize();

   v8::Isolate::CreateParams create_params;
   create_params.array_buffer_allocator = v8::ArrayBuffer::Allocator::NewDefaultAllocator();
   Isolate* isolate = v8::Isolate::New(create_params);

   printf("Sleeping...\n");
   usleep(1000 * 1000 * 100);
   printf("Done\n");
   return 0;
}
```

When i run this program, i can then check the number of threads the process has created with `ps -T -p <process_id>`, and i see that on my 8 core machine, v8 creates 7 extra threads all named "V8 WorkerThread", and on my 16 core machine i get 8 instances of this "V8 WorkerThread" created.

I am looking to understand what determines the number of extra threads v8 spawns and what the purpose of these threads are. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of worker threads, when not specified by the embedder (that's you!), is chosen based on the number of CPU cores. In the [current implementation](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/v8/src/libplatform/default-platform.cc?type=cs&q=SetThreadPoolSize&g=0&l=92), the formula is: `number_of_worker_threads = (number_of_CPU_cores - 1) up to a maximum of 8`, though this may change without notice. You can also specify your own worker thread pool size as an argument to `NewDefaultPlatform`.

The worker threads are used for various tasks that can be run in the background, mostly for garbage collection and optimized compilation.